# column().data() with orthogonal data instead of display?

Tags: datatables

I'm using [`column().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().data()) to get an array of all values in a column. It works fine on plain-text cells, but from those containing HTML, I'm getting the full HTML. Consider *Office* in the below example adapted from [live.datatables.net](http://live.datatables.net/).

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  console.log(table.column(2).data().toArray());
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="//nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="//nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td data-value="GB"><b>GB</b><i>Edinburgh</i></td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td data-value="US"><b>US</b><i>San Francisco</i></td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The console outputs:

```
[
  "<b>US</b><i>San Francisco</i>",
  "<b>GB</b><i>Edinburgh</i>"
]
```

But how do I make that call return e.g. just `"US"` instead of `"<b>US</b><i>San Francisco</i>"`?

According to [/manual/data/orthogonal-data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#HTML-5), a similar issue (i.e. having to keep machine-readable value next to a human-friendly [`display`](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#API-interface) value) already exists with the Filter and Sort features, and is solved using the `data-*` attributes.

> Consider for example currency data; for display it might be shown formatted with a currency sign and thousand separators, while sorting should happen numerically and searching on the data will accept either form.

So I guess the solution to my issue could be some `data-value` attribute, but I haven't found anything. Is it doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use `data-*` custom attributes.

But since you want your displayed data to show the HTML formatting, and since you probably do not want to interfere with sorting/filtering by forcing that column to *only* sort or filter on the country ID, I would recommend you avoid using the [pre-defined HTML5 attributes used by DataTables](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#HTML-5).

Instead, you can extract the data you need by iterating over the DataTable nodes:

```html
    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office in Country</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td data-country="GB"><b>GB</b><i> Edinburgh</i></td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior "Technical" Author</td>
                <td data-country="US"><b>US</b><i> San Francisco</i></td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

```js
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  const countries = Array.from(
    table.column(2).nodes(),
    country => country.getAttribute('data-country')
  );
  
  console.log( countries );
```

Here I use `<td data-country="xx">`, and then I use the DataTables API to iterate over the table's nodes and read the `data-country` attributes into an array:

```
[ "US", "GB" ]
```

There are probably various other ways you could solve this - but I think this is clear and concise.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it!

Answer (score 1):

The code I ended up with is a bit more generalised (so not only for countries, and supports `innerText`), but it's fully based on @andrewjames' answer, which is where the credit is due.

```
var values = Array.from(
    table.column(2).nodes(),
    function(cell) {
        // First, look for the dedicated attribute
        if (cell.hasAttribute('data-filter')) {
            return cell.getAttribute('data-filter');
        }
        // Otherwise, use the inner text of the table cell
        return cell.innerText;
    }
);
```